# Is it a correct way to put OpaquePointer into array in SQLite3?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, pointers

The project has multiple SQLite3 files with same SQL format, I used to open them separately:

```
var db1: OpaquePointer? = nil
var db2: OpaquePointer? = nil
var db3: OpaquePointer? = nil
```

I wondered if we can put **pointer** into an array or dictionary so as to save some code work, so I tried this:

```
var planDBDict = [String:OpaquePointer]()

for fileName in planArr {
    guard let dbPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "db") else {
        continue
    }
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    if sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
        planDBDict[fileName] = db
    } else {
        debugPrint("Failed to open \(fileName) database")
    }
}
```

And then read database depends on their names:

```
let db = planDBDict[fileName]
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    // do get data ....
}
```

They worked, but more slowly than ever. Is it a bad idea to do this?

Comment: OpaquePointer is struct which is a wrapper around an opaque C pointer. So it must be unwrapped first ... Think about it the same way as about any type eraser. That explain why it must be slower

Comment: @user3441734 I found encryption also cost speed, ok ignore speed, is it a better(legal) way to put it in array or dictionary? Thanks.